# Not able to restart nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

I try to restart my nginx server by the command.

```
sudo service nginx restart.
```

It gives me a error

```
* Restarting nginx nginx[fail]
```

When I check in error.log it provides me with the error

```
2016/04/24 06:01:45 [emerg] 12852#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/24 06:01:45 [emerg] 12852#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/24 06:01:45 [emerg] 12852#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/24 06:01:45 [emerg] 12852#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/24 06:01:45 [emerg] 12852#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/24 06:01:45 [emerg] 12852#0: still could not bind()
2016/04/24 06:13:49 [alert] 15033#0: mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, 52428800) failed (12: Cannot allocate memory)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a process that listens on that port. It might be apache for example, or another web server. Close that and start nginx

Comment: netstat -tulpn | grep :80

Comment: I had done that but it gives me "tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13890/nginx". On restart it should stop nginx first right?

Comment: mmmm...yes. Try to nginx stop. Make sure its stopped (with the same command), then try the restart again.

Comment: Even after "sudo service nginx stop". It gives cp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13890/nginx on netstat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110050/discussion-between-geo-paul-and-tudor-constantin).